How to implement the searchAfter and searchBefore in MongoDb?
I have written the code for SearchOptions and call to Aggregate search but it's not working. Error: SearchAfter does not contain a definition I'm using MongoDb Driver 2.22.0 version.
 var searchOptions = new SearchOptions<ProductModel>
            {
                Sort = sortOrder,
                IndexName = "products",
                CountOptions = new SearchCountOptions()
                {
                    Type = SearchCountType.Total
                },

                SearchAfter = request.PaginationType == "After" ? request.SequenceToken : null,
                SearchBefore = request.PaginationType == "Before" ?  request.SequenceToken : null
            };


var result = _productsCollection.Aggregate()
 .Search(searchDefinition, searchOptions)
 .Limit(pageSize)
 .Project(projectionDefinition)
 .As<ProductModel>()
 .ToList();

MongoDB Search Syntax below:
{
  $search: {
    "index": "<index-name>",
    "<operator-name>"|"<collector-name>": {
      <operator-specification>|<collector-specification>
    },
    "highlight": {
      <highlight-options>
    },
    "concurrent": true | false,
    "count": {
      <count-options>
    },
    "searchAfter"|"searchBefore": "<encoded-token>",
    "scoreDetails": true| false,
    "sort": {
      <fields-to-sort>: 1 | -1
    },
    "returnStoredSource": true | false,
    "tracking": {
      <tracking-option>
    }
   }
}

Is there anyone implemented this please help me.

do not post links, use plain text instead

You can try to construct $search aggregation query directly to handle paging logic. Here  is the sample, you can give it a try.

Or check the official version update instructions to see which driver version supports SearchAfter.

@JasonPan I'm already using "searchDefinition". So How can construct $search ? I tried but it's not working.

"not working" can mean a lot of things, so please provide what you expect and what exactly doesn't work
